# Require/include Error PHP

Tags: php

I have a strange error and I don't know what is going on. Here's the line of code:

```
 require(__DIR__.'/../../modeles/newsletter/functions.php');
```

My folder looks like this: 
[image: this]

And here's my 
[image: error]:

I've tried a lot of combinations, but all failed...why?

Thanks

Comment: No need for hi,hello, etc., also, make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error do not come from this line:

```
require(__DIR__.'/../../modeles/newsletter/functions.php');
```

it's come from the inclusion of the connexion_sql.php in your modeles/newsletter/functions.php file.
Open your modeles/newsletter/functions.php and replace at line 2 :

```
require_once('/../../modeles/connexion_sql.php');
```

with

```
require_once('../modeles/connexion_sql.php');
```